# Unused arguments error when tunning parameters on costumed SVM function

Tags: r, svm

## My goal is to tune a slighty modified version of the function SVM applyed to different kernel functions but I receive an error in the process.

This is the function that fits the model and computes the errors:

```
train.svm <-function(myKernel, myC){
  time0 <- Sys.time()

  switch(myKernel,
         linear={model <- svm(class ~ ., data = train, type="C-classification", cost=myC, kernel="linear", scale = FALSE)},
         poly.2={model <- svm(class ~ ., data = train, type="C-classification", cost=myC, kernel="polynomial", degree=2, coef0=1, scale = FALSE)},
         poly.3={model <- svm(class ~ ., data = train, type="C-classification", cost=myC, kernel="polynomial", degree=3, coef0=1, scale = FALSE)},
         RBF={model    <- svm(class ~ ., data = train, type="C-classification", cost=myC, kernel="radial", scale = FALSE)},
         stop("Enter one of 'linear', 'poly.2', 'poly.3', 'radial'"))

  pred_train <- predict(model, subset(train, select = -class), decision.values = TRUE)
  pred_test  <- predict(model, subset(test , select = -class), decision.values = TRUE)

  error_train <- sum(pred_train != train$class)/length(train$class)*100
  error_test <- sum(pred_test != test$class)/length(test$class)*100

  c(myC,error_train, error_test, Sys.time() -time0)
}
```

and I try to tune it with the following command:

```
obj <- tune(train.svm, class ~ ., data = train, 
            ranges = list(myKernel = c("linear", "poly.2", "poly.3", "RBF"),cost = 2^(-4:4)),
            tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "fix")
        )
```

but receive the following error :

```
Error in (function (myKernel, myC)  : 
  unused arguments (data = list(c(43, 35, 43, 52, 57, ...
```

the data I am running inside this SVM is :

```
V3   V4   V5   V6  class
43 -146   33 -108   0
35  -63  -89  101   0
43 -149   33  -79   0
52 -122  -22 -113   1
57 -198 -112  -69   1
```

I also realise that **I am not telling the `tune` function over which value should make the criteria of which sets of values are the best**.

Comment: are all of your variables factors/integers? do you have any characters because that might not work

Comment: Yes, every feature is numerical (Integers)